# Creating an Array of tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var buttonArray = [
    document.getElementById('underline'),
    document.getElementById('bold'),
    document.getElementById('italic'),
    document.getElementById('tnr'),
    document.getElementById('ss'),
    document.getElementById('red'),
    document.getElementById('green'),
    document.getElementById('blue')
];
```

Can you do this? Or is it too abstract?

Comment: *Can you do this*... did you *try*? (Yes you can).

Comment: Have you tried running your code? Or are you trying to create elements instead of just selecting them?

Comment: You just did this: so yes.

Comment: Why don't you give all those elements the same class? Then it would be `documents.getElementsByClassName('foo')` or `document.querySelectorAll('.foo')`. But apart from that it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; that will work fine.

You can make it more elegant like this:

```
var buttonArray = [ "underline", ... ]
                  .map(document.getElementById.bind(document));
```

Comment: Surely it's more elegant, but `map` and `bind` aren't widely supported yet so you'll need to shim them for older browsers. A simple for-loop to transform the tags into elements is always supported and still quite elegant.

Comment: @Slaks: Why do you need to call ultimately `bind(document)` on `getElementById`? I noticed that it won't work otherwise, but wouldn't `document.getElementById` already be bound to `document`?

Comment: @okiharaherbst: No; `document.getElementById` is a reference to an unbound function.  `this` is set depending on the reference you _call_ it from.

Comment: @SLaks: My bad, an immediate similarity with reflection in Java is, indeed, that the `invoke(...)` method on a `Method` object also takes an instance to call it (or bind it) upon as first argument. Many thanks anyway (reading up on `bind()` in JS – The definitive guide).

Comment: @okiharaherbst: Javascript has no equivalent to reflection.  JS allows the function itself to be passed as an object.

Comment: @SLaks: Clearly, `for(var e in someobject) { ... }` is a way of inspecting the members of an object. Whether you call this ability reflection or type introspection is really up to you but JS **does** feature it. Functions as objects: yes, definitely.